# I can’t disable splashscreen in my apps

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, splash-screen, ngcordova

I have deleted following lines in my config.xml

```
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
```

And I have removed also the ngCordova splashscreen plugin, and rebuilded all

```
ionic platform remove ios &&  ionic platform add ios && ionic build ios
```

But when the app starts, it still showing the splashscreen.
(I have deleted the png from resources).
What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried deleting the App from your device, and then reinstalling?  Things like splash screens may hang around even though you deleted them (your programming environment may not send some sort of delete command for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for late answer. The problem was that's the iOS it's not accepting apps without splash screen which is required as Apple says on their website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html

> Every app needs an app icon and a launch file or image.